# Responsive height content background color

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm using Kube CSS framework to create a demo site at [www.dreametry.nl/ddfleurs](http://www.dreametry.nl/ddfleurs) . It was going well until I came across a problem with the main content background color. On the desktop the white background grows with the content, but not on a mobile device. The problems is the white background stops half way the content.

I tried using several styles, the only changes was with

```
.content { min-height: 650px; }
```

But then the background height is too much on mobiles.

Including `height: 60%;` to the previous code doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried setting `html` and `body` tags width & height to `100%`?

Comment: Can i do that for a responsive design?

Comment: why not? as long as they are in `%`, you are not going to break anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in two ways.

by giving

`overflow: hidden`

to `class="unit-75 content"`

or by clearing the div

```
<div class="unit-75 content" >
   <!--All you HTML-->

   <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: On second thought: `overflow: hidden` doesn't work for my case. Adding `clear: both` does. Thanks Tushar!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow:hidden` on the wrapper element (body tag, a particular div etc) to force it to adapt to the height of elements contained IF your layout uses floats.